# How do I convert unicode character into \x06\x23\x06\x31\x06\x46\x06\x28

Tags: php, unicode

How do i convert character 火 into something like this \x06\x23\x06\x31\x06\x46\x06\x28

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-16');
echo "\x06\x23\x06\x31\x06\x46\x06\x28";

?>
```

Code printed: ؊أرن

Comment: maybe `echo strtoupper(bin2hex(iconv('UTF-16', 'UCS-2', '火')));`